# D3.js jumpy zoom behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am trying to do a zoomable heatmap and the community here on SO have helped massively, however I am now stuck the whole day today trying to fix a glitch and I am hitting the wall every single time.

The issue is that the zoom looks jumpy, ie the plot is rendered fine, however when the zoom event is triggered some kind of transformation happens that changes the axes and the scaling in an abrupt way. The code below demonstrates this issue. The problem does not always happen, it depends on the heatmap dimension and/or the number of the dots.

Some similar cases from people with the same problem here on SO turned out to be that the zoom was not applied to the correct object but I think I am not doing that mistake. Many thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .axis text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
    }
    
    .x.axis path {
      //display: none;
    }
    
    .chart rect {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    
    .chart text {
      fill: white;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      text-anchor: end;
    }
    
    #tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #2B292E;
      color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      pointer-events: none;
      /*dont trigger events on the tooltip*/
      padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
      text-align: center;
      opacity: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Heatmap Chart</title>

  <!-- Reference style.css -->
  <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->

  <!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
  <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='heatmap.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart">
    <svg width="550" height="1000"></svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    var dataset = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 60; i++) { //360
      for (j = 1; j < 70; j++) { //75
        dataset.push({
          xKey: i,
          xLabel: "xMark " + i,
          yKey: j,
          yLabel: "yMark " + j,
          val: Math.random() * 25,

        })
      }
    };

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
      .select("svg")

    var xLabels = [],
      yLabels = [];
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);
        var j = 0;
        while (dataset[j + 1].xLabel == dataset[j].xLabel) {
          yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
          j++;
        }
        yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
      } else {
        if (dataset[i - 1].xLabel == dataset[i].xLabel) {
          //do nothing
        } else {
          xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);
        }
      }
    };



    var margin = {
      top: 0,
      right: 25,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 75
    };

    var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var dotSpacing = 0,
      dotWidth = width / (2 * (xLabels.length + 1)),
      dotHeight = height / (2 * yLabels.length);

    //    var dotWidth = 1,
    //        dotHeight = 3,
    //        dotSpacing = 0.5;


    var daysRange = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.xKey
      }),
      days = daysRange[1] - daysRange[0];

    var hoursRange = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.yKey
      }),
      hours = hoursRange[1] - hoursRange[0];

    var tRange = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.val
      }),
      tMin = tRange[0],
      tMax = tRange[1];

    //    var width = (dotWidth * 2 + dotSpacing) * days,
    //        height = (dotHeight * 2 + dotSpacing) * hours;
    //    var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    //        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var colors = ['#2C7BB6', '#00A6CA', '#00CCBC', '#90EB9D', '#FFFF8C', '#F9D057', '#F29E2E', '#E76818', '#D7191C'];

    // the scale
    var scale = {
      x: d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-1, d3.max(dataset, d => d.xKey)])
        .range([-1, width]),
      y: d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d.yKey)])
        .range([height, 0]),
      //.range([(dotHeight * 2 + dotSpacing) * hours, dotHeight * 2 + dotSpacing]),
    };

    var xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(xLabels).range([0, width]),
      yBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(yLabels).range([height, 0]);

    var axis = {
      x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat((d, e) => xLabels[d]),
      y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).tickFormat((d, e) => yLabels[d]),
    };


    function updateScales(data) {
      scale.x.domain([-1, d3.max(data, d => d.xKey)]),
        scale.y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.yKey)])
    }

    var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
      .domain([0, colors.length - 1, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d.val;
      })])
      .range(colors);



    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([dotWidth, dotHeight])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("id", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    // SVG canvas
    svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      //.call(zoom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Clip path
    svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height + dotHeight);


    // Heatmap dots
    var heatDotsGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .append("g");

    heatDotsGroup.call(zoom);



    //Create X axis
    var renderXAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + scale.y(-1) + ")")
      .call(axis.x)

    //Create Y axis
    var renderYAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(axis.y);


    function zoomed() {
      d3.event.transform.y = 0;
      d3.event.transform.x = Math.min(d3.event.transform.x, 5);
      d3.event.transform.x = Math.max(d3.event.transform.x, (1 - d3.event.transform.k) * width);
      d3.event.transform.k = Math.max(d3.event.transform.k, 1);
      //console.log(d3.event.transform)

      // update: rescale x axis
      renderXAxis.call(axis.x.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.x)));

      heatDotsGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform.toString().replace(/scale\((.*?)\)/, "scale($1, 1)"));
    }

    svg.call(renderPlot, dataset)

    function renderPlot(selection, dataset) {
      //updateScales(dataset);

      heatDotsGroup.selectAll("ellipse")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return scale.x(d.xKey) - xBand.bandwidth();
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return scale.y(d.yKey) + yBand.bandwidth();
        })
        .attr("rx", dotWidth)
        .attr("ry", dotHeight)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return colorScale(d.val);
        })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          $("#tooltip").html("X: " + d.xKey + "<br/>Y: " + d.yKey + "<br/>Value: " + Math.round(d.val * 100) / 100);
          var xpos = d3.event.pageX + 10;
          var ypos = d3.event.pageY + 20;
          $("#tooltip").css("left", xpos + "px").css("top", ypos + "px").animate().css("opacity", 1);
        }).on("mouseout", function() {
          $("#tooltip").animate({
            duration: 500
          }).css("opacity", 0);
        });


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the zoom scaleExtend

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, dotHeight])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Call the zoom on the **whole** svg not on the heatDotsGroup because this node receives the tranformation, and also **not** on the `g` node that has the graph transformation here variable `svg` (to keep things a bit obscure)

```
svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .call(zoom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// heatDotsGroup.call(zoom);
```

Don't limit the zoom scale `k` in the tick. Already taken care of by the `scaleExtent()`

```
//   d3.event.transform.k = Math.max(d3.event.transform.k, 1);
```

Why calculate all the `d3.max()` when you already have calculated the `d3.extent()` of these values?

Comment: Thanks a million! That works fine. I spent the whole Sunday banging my head to fix this. Many thanks again!!

Comment: If you change something to the original code and you get strange behavior, remove all changes and apply them one by one to see who is responsible.

Comment: Yes, thats what i try to do. I had an other issue with the tick labels, the text was misplaced but i managed to fix this. In general however, I find it difficult to locate where the problem is. Initially, in this case for example, I was calling zoom on the svg, then I changed it to heatDotsGroup (and I was fairly confident that was fine) but the issue persisted and I thought that something was misspecified in the transform calls. Many many thanks once again :)

Comment: using `.scaleExtent([dotWidth, dotHeight])` has the result that the zoom factor (`k`) is only allowed between 50 and 60 (example). So as soon as you use the mouse wheel it has a zoom factor of 50. The max zoom factor is `xSizeEllipseAtMaxZoom / xSizeEllipseAtZoom1` so dotWidth or dotHeight is way to big. Use `.scaleExtent([1, xSizeEllipseAtMaxZoom / xSizeEllipseAtZoom1])`

Comment: Brilliant! I makes a lot more sense now! I also now understand why my handling of the min zoom scale with the line `d3.event.transform.k = Math.max(d3.event.transform.k, 1);` is redundant since this is taken care of the `.scale.Extent` call right after you attach the zoom on the svg. Many many thanks!